# PKCS #7 Signing

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, pkcs#7

What should i write to the file in order to verify signature, when we are signing data using following class 
*org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData* and *org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator*

Thanks a lot

I have written code to achieve this but i am getting exception

```
public class T2 {
    public static String ROOT_ALIAS = "root";
    public static String INTERMEDIATE_ALIAS = "intermediate";
    public static String END_ENTITY_ALIAS = "end";
    public static String PLAIN_TEXT = "Hello World!123";
    private static final char[] KEY_PASSWORD = "keyPassword".toCharArray();

    public static CMSSignedData signData(KeyStore keyStore,
            byte[] plainTextToSign) throws Exception {
        // GET THE PRIVATE KEY
        PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(END_ENTITY_ALIAS,
                KEY_PASSWORD);

        Certificate[] chain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(END_ENTITY_ALIAS);
        CertStore certsAndCRLs = CertStore.getInstance("Collection",
                new CollectionCertStoreParameters(Arrays.asList(chain)), "BC");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) chain[0];

        // set up the generator
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        gen.addSigner(key, cert, CMSSignedDataGenerator.DIGEST_SHA224);
        gen.addCertificatesAndCRLs(certsAndCRLs);

        // create the signed-data object
        CMSProcessable data = new CMSProcessableByteArray(plainTextToSign);
        CMSSignedData signed = gen.generate(data, "BC");

        // recreate
        signed = new CMSSignedData(data, signed.getEncoded());
        // ContentInfo conInf = signed.getContentInfo();
        // CMSProcessable sigContent = signed.getSignedContent();

        new File("D:\\pkcs7\\encrypted-file.p7b");
        FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                "D:\\pkcs7\\encrypted-file.p7b");
        fileOuputStream.write(signed.getEncoded());
        // fileOuputStream.flush();
        fileOuputStream.close();
        return signed;
    }

    public static boolean verifyData(KeyStore keyStore) throws Exception {

        File file = new File("D:\\pkcs7\\encrypted-file.p7b");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] signedByte = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        fileInputStream.read(signedByte);
        fileInputStream.close();

        // verification step
        X509Certificate rootCert = (X509Certificate) keyStore
                .getCertificate(ROOT_ALIAS);

        CMSSignedData signed = new CMSSignedData(signedByte);
        if (isValidSignature(signed, rootCert)) {
            System.out.println("verification succeeded");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("verification failed");
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Take a CMS SignedData message and a trust anchor and determine if the
     * message is signed with a valid signature from a end entity entity
     * certificate recognized by the trust anchor rootCert.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static boolean isValidSignature(CMSSignedData signedData,
            X509Certificate rootCert) throws Exception {

        boolean[] bArr = new boolean[2];
        bArr[0] = true;
        CertStore certsAndCRLs = signedData.getCertificatesAndCRLs(
                "Collection", "BC");
        SignerInformationStore signers = signedData.getSignerInfos();
        Iterator it = signers.getSigners().iterator();

        if (it.hasNext()) {
            SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next();
            SignerId signerConstraints = signer.getSID();
            signerConstraints.setKeyUsage(bArr);
            PKIXCertPathBuilderResult result = buildPath(rootCert,
                    signer.getSID(), certsAndCRLs);
            return signer.verify(result.getPublicKey(), "BC");
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Build a path using the given root as the trust anchor, and the passed in
     * end constraints and certificate store.
     * <p>
     * Note: the path is built with revocation checking turned off.
     */
    public static PKIXCertPathBuilderResult buildPath(X509Certificate rootCert,
            X509CertSelector endConstraints, CertStore certsAndCRLs)
            throws Exception {
        CertPathBuilder builder = CertPathBuilder.getInstance("PKIX", "BC");
        PKIXBuilderParameters buildParams = new PKIXBuilderParameters(
                Collections.singleton(new TrustAnchor(rootCert, null)),
                endConstraints);

        buildParams.addCertStore(certsAndCRLs);
        buildParams.setRevocationEnabled(false);

        return (PKIXCertPathBuilderResult) builder.build(buildParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you should write in the file or how you should write your code?

Comment: How should i write code?

Comment: Just a question: is this code substantially different from the earlier question? Please try and followup / accept answers of your questions Arvind...

Answer (score 0):

When the signature is wrapping, you don't need to write anything to the file - the product of the signature operation is your data wrapped with the signature packet. Note that such signed data can not be directly handled by applications that handle the original unsigned data. Eg. if you sign the PDF document using wrapping PKCS#7/CMS signature, Adobe Reader won't be able to open the signed data directly (until the signature is removed). The signature is verified by feeding signed data to the verification procedure.

With detached signature the product of the signing operation is the signature block itself which you can store in a separate file or as an alternate data stream on some filesystems or in a separate field in the database. Your original data remain intact in this case. The signature is verified by feeding original data and the signature block to the verification procedure.

Comment: What i understood is 
suppose my text is : 12345
signature is : 89
so signed data will become sth like #12$34!#!@589
now this data will be written to file and we will read this data from file ,and verify than we will remove this signature and get original content back.
**If this is correct  how do i do it using bouncy castle **

Comment: @Arvind your understanding is correct. I don't know how to do this in BouncyCastle. We offer our own solutions for cryptography in Java.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS